# WebP Formatted images not Always Displaying on iOS

Tags: ios, image, webp

In order to speed HTML page loads, I've converted images to webp format and use the "picture" element as follows:

```
<picture>
    <source data-srcset="images/gallery/urban.webp" type="image/webp">
    <source data-srcset=images/gallery/urban.jpg" type="image/jpeg">
    <img data-src="images/gallery/urban.jpg" alt="Alt Title" style="">
</picture>
```

On my tests in Chrome, IE, Edge and Firefox on the desktop, this seems to work fine.  On Chrome, in developer mode, when I run under emulation mode for mobile devices, it works too.

But when I test on an iPhone with iOS 12, not all of the images render.  It happens on both Safari and Chrome.  A few of the larger images are displayed as gray areas.  I hadn't seen that before during development.  When I change the  element back to just the jpg , it renders OK:

```
<img src="images/gallery/urban.jpg" alt="Alt Title" style="">
```

I'm not sure the best way to fix this.  Maybe there is something wrong with the markup.  Or maybe I should consider it a bug and try to work around it by forcing jpg/png images when the operating system is iOS?  (by using CSS or HTML or Javascript?) But the problem seems to be affecting only certain larger images.  It is a bit of a hassle to have to manually test to determine which images should be "picture" and which should be just "img".

Answer (score 7):

WebP was designed by Google for use in Google Chrome. Unfortunately, WebP is not supported in Apple's Safari web browser.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250073758

Only starting with iOS 14 (released end of September 2020), Safari on iOS supports webp.

Comment: I have the same problem in Google Chrome iOS. Some pictures don't show

Answer (score 0):

Only the larger files being affected maybe suggests these are animated images similar to,  but better quality than gifs.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).